# When should I specify that top and bottom copper component pads are to be pre-tinned?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, solder-mask

My circuit boards come from the fab house with solder pads in a pre-tinned state.  Maybe I did not think to specify this - or not! Prior to reflowing should I stencil more solder or should I just apply flux, place the components and reflow. It begs the question; when should pre-tinned pads be used.

Comment: Which fan house may we know?

Comment: JLCPCB ... The quality appears to be very good and I will hot-plate solder it

Comment: They mention surface finishes in their FAQ: https://jlcpcb.com/quote/pcbOrderFaq/PCB%20Surface%20Finish . If I understand your question properly now I would say you must apply more solder, the HASL coating isn’t sufficient to make good solder joints - I’ve tried and it failed miserably.

Comment: Also note that there is HASL and lead-free HASL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Circuit boards always have a finish on them. If they didn't, the copper would quickly oxidize beyond the point of solderability! There are several different finishes available, each with their advantages and disadvantages:

- HASL (Hot Air Solder Levelling) is a process of essentially just dipping the board in solder and then using jets of hot air to blow off the excess. It comes in both leaded and lead-free varieties, and is the cheapest option. This is most likely what they did with your board; it's usually the default option and other finishes require a small surcharge. HASL's main drawback is that it's not very flat; it can be easy for BGA parts to find a couple balls just not making contact with the board.
- ENIG (Electroless Nickel/Immersion Gold) is the next step up from HASL. Here, a plating of nickel is applied to all the bare copper, then a very thin layer of gold is plated on top of that. This is a very flat finish, and one that resists corrosion very well (gold is known for that, after all), but an expensive one. It used to be susceptible to something called "black pad syndrome", where excess phosphorus in the chemicals used could render the occasional pad blackened and nonconductive, but ever since it was discovered what causes it, black pad syndrome has gotten rarer.
- ENEPIG (Electroless Nickel/Electroless Palladium/Immersion Gold) is ENIG with an extra layer of palladium in the middle. This prevents black pad syndrome at the cost of, well, cost. ENEPIG is more expensive than ENIG, but otherwise has near identical performance.
- ENIAg (Electroless Nickel/Immersion silver(Ag), sometimes just called "Immersion silver") is ENIG with silver instead of gold. Silver is more solderable than either gold or nickel, and a good deal cheaper, but much more susceptible to corrosion. ENIAg boards need to be soldered within a few months of manufacture, less if in an environment with lots of sulfurous pollution.
- Hard gold is a plating of a relatively thick layer of gold (I believe with alloying elements to make it more mechanically strong), used where corrosion resistance needs to be maintained for a long period of time under some mechanical stress. It's almost exclusively used on card edge connectors (like those used for computer buses like ISA, PCI, or PCIe). Because of the sheer amount of gold used, it's quite expensive. Frequently, this type of finish is applied only to the edge of a board, where the edge connector would make contact; this selective application is sometimes called "gold fingers".
- OSP (Organic Solderability Preservatives) is a layer of organic polymers that act as a physical barrier to corrosion, but can be easily burned away by heat and flux when soldering. This also doesn't last too long; boards need to be soldered within a few months of opening the package. Since the OSP finish is transparent, a board with OSP looks like it just has bare copper.
- There are probably other finishes, but none that I'm personally aware of. If anyone knows any I missed, let me know.

Some fabs may give you an option to get a board with bare copper and no finish, but you shouldn't take that option unless you know what you're doing and really need bare copper.

Like I said, it's likely your board has a HASL finish. Most PCB fabs let you specify what finish you'd like, but anything other than HASL usually costs more. Personally, I usually go with lead-free HASL for my boards, or ENIG if I need something special. ENIG isn't really prohibitively expensive until you're mass-producing boards; there really isn't that much gold (typical thickness of the gold on an ENIG board is 1~5 μ" (microinches), on top of about 200 μ" of nickel). It does add a few bucks to the cost, though.

A board with a HASL finish does not have enough solder on the board to attach any components. You should stencil on some solder paste or solder it with an iron and solder wire, just like any other board. The solder on the pads is there for no reason other than to protect them from oxygen.

Comment: Thanks for this. Clearly, it is HASL, I can visually see it now that I understand. I learned something today.  I have one more question about the solder flux (drying before I'm finished placing components) but I'll ask separately so maybe others can benefit from the question/answer.

Comment: ENIG tends to store better if the boards may have to be stored for a long time or if the storage conditions cannot be well controlled (temp and humidity). Or this is at least what I have been told. Also, ENIG is more uniformly flat than HASL, so when BGA parts are involved, ENIG is typically preferred.

Comment: @mkeith I believe I mentioned both of those in my answer; was it unclear? If so, I can edit it.

Comment: @Hearth Thanks. I enjoyed reading this. My curiosity took me to [this page](https://www.sharrettsplating.com/blog/enepig-plating-printed-circuit-boards/) where it appears they claim that ENEPIG is **cheaper** than ENIG because of the allowed thinner layer of gold. Which suggests that would be a better default choice if not HASL. What do you think about what they write there?

Comment: @jonk I know my usual PCB fab charges more for ENEPIG than for ENIG. Palladium is also a precious metal, though one that fluctuates wildly in price--it's possible it may be cheaper sometimes and more expensive others? --Oh, it looks like their claim is that ENEPIG is cheaper than ENEG, not ENIG; I've honestly never heard of ENEG (electrolytic nickel/electrolytic gold) before, but they say that it has much thicker gold than ENIG or ENEPIG. They don't specifically mention cost as a drawback of ENIG in their comparison section.

Comment: @mkeith Ah! I misunderstood what you were going for there. I'll just leave it as a comment then.

Answer (score 3):

Copper would oxidize and become unsolderable if left exposed to the air, so PCB fabrication companies offer a range of finishes like gold or HASL.

If yours look tinned you probably got Hot Air Solder Leveling which means hot solder was applied then the excess blown off with hot air. It's one of the cheapest finishes and it is fine unless you need it very flat or with gold fingers for connectors.

This is just to protect copper and doesn't leave enough tin on the board to solder your components, so you need to add your own.

Comment: Yes it appears to be HASL.  When I study it under magnification I see that the solder mask  works very well.  The thin pads appear to be properly plated with no bridging.